# separate distinct strings with common characters using stringr::str_detect() in R

Tags: r, regex

i have the following sample character vector:

```
sample_dat <- c("Q2", "Q20", "Q21", "Q23_8_T", "Q21_fct", "Q2_fct7", "Q20_fct7_4", "Q2_fct7_4")
```

From this vector of strings, I want to isolate those that share in common the initial prefix using a regular expression so that I might be able to use it again in a function, such that the desired subset of strings for prefix = "Q2" would be the result of the following code snippet:

```
(desired_subset <- sample_dat[c(1, 6, 8)])
```

That is, the desired output should be `c("Q2", "Q2_fct7", "Q2_fct7_4")`

I tried using stringr::str_detect() to reproduce the `desired_subset` using a regular expression, but i am unable to have desired_subset[1] enter the result:

```
library(stringr)

sample_dat[str_detect(string = sample_dat, pattern = "Q2_")]
```

in the case above, too few results are returned., I am missing
"Q2" itself.

Whereas in the code below, too many results are returned. For example "Q20" and "Q21" are returned which is not what I want.

```
sample_dat[str_detect(string = sample_dat, pattern = "Q2")]
```

eventually, I'd like to use it in a function like so:

```
subset_str <- function(str, prefix){
  substitute(prefix)
  str_set <- str_detect(string = str, pattern = paste0(eval(prefix),'_'))
  return(str[str_set])
}
```

such that

`subset_str(sample_dat, "Q2")` would return ONLY

`c("Q2", "Q2_fct7", "Q2_fct7_4")` and

`subset_str(sample_dat, "Q20")` would return ONLY

`c("Q20", "Q20_fct7")`

Perhaps there is someone who might be able to help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the pattern as the intended substring to match ("Q20") that is the start of the string (`^`) followed by either a `_` or (`|`) it is the end (`$`) of the string

```
grep("^Q20(_|$)", sample_dat, value = TRUE)
#[1] "Q20"        "Q20_fct7_4"


grep("^Q2(_|$)", sample_dat, value = TRUE)
#[1] "Q2"        "Q2_fct7"   "Q2_fct7_4"
```

which can be wrapped into a function

```
subset_str <- function(string, pattern){
     grep(pattern, string, value = TRUE)
 }
```

---

Or the same pattern in `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
sample_dat[str_detect(string = sample_dat, pattern = "Q2(_|$)")]
#[1] "Q2"        "Q2_fct7"   "Q2_fct7_4"
```